# Token become null after updating data user for the second time (flutter)

Tags: flutter, user-input

When I edit an user profile for the 1st time it succeeds, but fails when i do it again(2nd time). I think it's because the token I sent to back-end is null. Any idea why this is happening?

The code for updating user profile:

```
Future<UserModel> updateProfile({
    String? first_name,
    String? profile_picture,
    String? last_name,
    String? email,
    String? password,
    String? city,
    String? address,
    String? province,
    String? zip_code,
    String? district,
    String? phone_number,
    String? old_password,
    String? password_confirmation,
  }) async {
    String uuid = await UserPreference().getUuid();
    String getToken = await UserPreference().getToken();
    print(getToken);
    var url = '$baseUrl/customer/$uuid';
    var headers = {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      HttpHeaders.authorizationHeader: "Bearer $getToken"
    };
    var response = await http.post(
      Uri.parse(url),
      headers: headers,
    );

    try {
      print(response.body);
      var data = jsonDecode(response.body)['data'];
      UserModel user = UserModel.fromJson(data['profile']);
      SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
      prefs.setString('first_name', user.first_name!);
      prefs.setString('last_name', user.last_name!);
      prefs.setString('profile_picture', user.profile_picture!);
      prefs.setString('city', user.city!);
      prefs.setString('address', user.address!);
      prefs.setString('province', user.province!);
      prefs.setString('zip_code', user.zip_code!);
      prefs.setString('district', user.district!);
      prefs.setString('phone_number', user.phone_number!);

      UserPreference().saveUserData(user);

      return user;
    } catch (e) {
      throw Exception(e);
    }
  }
```

Comment: you get token from here.  `UserPreference().getToken();` then you need to debug on that method, 
is `print( getToken)` return null too?

Comment: thank you for suggestion, i realized i didnt bring the token to server as well that makes the token null. its fixed now